Research into the functionality and performance of robot with and without ros2_control
I am currently looking into doing a research paper on the performance and functionality (including advantages and disadvantages) of using ros2_control opposed to for example a driver that starts a node. I am hoping to get some advice here as to how people would approach the research and what steps I should take. Also additional information or articles would be more than welcome.
My current idea is:

Do a literature study with the available articles on the advantages and disadvantages of using ros2_control.
Perform an experiment where I combine latency etc of the system when using a ros2_control hardware component for my Roboteq Motor Controller opposed to using a driver that simply starts a node.

Any ideas and help are more than welcome. Thanks in advance.
